# Add class to a dynamic height div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a "div#area" with a dynamic contents ,so div height is also dynamic ,what I want is when it's height is greater than 650px  add class ".over".
I use this script and it's not working:

```
<script>
    if ($('div#area').height() > 650) {
       $(this).addClass('over');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#area').height() > 650) {
        $('#area').addClass('over');
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` doesn't refers to `$('div#area')` when you execute the `addClass` statement. You can store the reference in a variable and use it.

```
var elem = $('div#area'); //Store a refrence to element
if (elem.height() > 650) {
   elem.addClass('over');
}
```

Comment: Because the OP uses `this` out of context, and @Satpal doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var area = $('div #area');
 if (area.height() > 650) {
   area.addClass('over');
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  if ($('#area').height() > 650) {
     $(this).addClass('over');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This solution wont work as `$(this)` wont refer to `$('div#area')`.